# Support and information for web apps on IOS 17

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, progressive-web-apps

I was regularly running tests with a web app (PWA) installed via the Safari browser. However, yesterday, during testing, I noticed that the web app no longer installs correctly. It is essential to underline that all checks carried out with PageSpeed returned a positive result with a green tick. However, when I try to install the web app, it seems that standalone or full screen mode doesn't work properly. Basically, if I open the link, Safari opens as if I were visiting the web app via a URL.

Also, I noticed that on an older iPad the problem doesn't occur. Do you have information on this? Is it possible that with iOS 17.4 Apple has disabled the ability to install web apps? I also ran tests on famous web apps such as X, Pinterest and Squoosh.app, and with iOS 17 the web apps are not opened in STANDALONE mode, while on the iPad it seems to work correctly.
I accept advice and suggestions, thanks in advance

I tried to install the web app on iPhone 11 PRO MAX with iOS 17.4 without obtaining positive results. However, on an older iPad, the web app installs and runs without issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in the beta of iOS 17.4. Or… Apple did this on purpose. Since it’s only for phones located in the EU.

More info:
https://open-web-advocacy.org/blog/did-apple-just-break-web-apps-in-ios17.4-beta-eu/